# Copy a dataset B for each variable in dataset A

Tags: merge, sas

I have the two following datasets:

*Dataset A*:

```
ID  
A      
B      
C
```

*Dataset B*:

```
Age 
35        
49      
53
```

And I want to copy paste B to each ID of A:

```
ID  Age 
A   35
A   49
A   53
B   35
B   49
...
```

For the moment I do this with a %do cicle but is there a more elegant way to do this? With a single PROC SQL or Datastep for example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your code.  Is there a reason you do this with `%do` ?  For SQL look into `CROSS JOIN`

Comment: @Richard simply because I couldn't figure out a way to do it in another way. Thanks for the cross join indication. It also works. Also, I didn't know it was called a cartesian product which would help me with the search. The Do cycle is convoluted (hence asking for a simpler solution).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL to perform a Cartesian product to get all combinations.

For example:

```
/* setup id data */
data have1;
   input id $char1.;
   datalines;
A
B
C
;

/* setup age data */
data have2;
   input age 8.;
   datalines;
35
49
53
;

/* perform Cartesian product */
proc sql noprint;
   create table
      want
   as
   select
      *
   from
       have1
      ,have2
   ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for macro code.  You can use the `POINT=` option on the `SET` statement to do this in a data step.

```
data want;
  set a;
  do p=1 to nobs;
    set b point=p nobs=nobs;
    output;
  end;
run;
```